# Copy Document Title Using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, return-value, google-docs

I want to copy the text from the title within this document, but I am only used to using Google App Script in sheets, not docs:
[image: Where the text is in the document]

I have tried lot of different methods, but nothing is populating in Logger.log(), so I am not sure it is working. Currently, all I want to return is the text in the Title, so I can go on to search for this in a spreadsheet. So far I have the following:

```
function autoFill() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var searchResult = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH);
  var searchHeading = searchResult.getElement(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.TITLE);
```

The only part of the document that has the format of Title is the first line in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that using Regular Expression would be able to identify the text needed:

```
 function autoFill() {
  var ss = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = ss.getBody();
  var header = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader();
  var contents = body.getText();
  var racm = SpreadsheetApp.openById('[enter sheet ID').getSheetByName('Risks & Controls matrix');
  var lr = racm.getLastRow();
  var colID = racm.getRange(1,1,lr,1).getValues();

//you need to tweak below to the control name pattern

  var regexName = /\w+[-]\w+[-]\w+/   //use website: regexr.com to create & www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-regular-expressions/
  var titleFound=regexName.exec(contents)[0];

let row = colID.findIndex(users => {return users[0] == titleFound})+1;
```

Then goes on to finding the relevant data in the ranges from the spreadsheet and .replaceText() within the doc.

Works really well.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to find the paragraph with the Heading style Title.  In my Doc I have a line of text "This is some text" with style Title.

```
function findTitle() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let paras = body.getParagraphs();
    let text = null;
    paras.some( para => {
        let attribs = para.getAttributes();
        if( attribs["HEADING"] === DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.TITLE ) {
          text = para.getText();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    );
    console.log(text);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
8:08:39 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:08:39 AM  Info    This is some text
8:08:39 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```